# Using Cloud Formation provisioned security group with specific subnet

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudformation

### Summary

I'm attempting to create an AWS CloudFormation template which contains an instance for which I want to select a particular subnet. If I specify the subnet ID then I get the following error `The parameter groupName cannot be used with the parameter subnet`. From reading [this thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=93929) it appears I need to provide security group IDs - not names. How can I create a security group in CloudFormation and then get its ID after the fact?

### Details

The relevant part of the instance config is as follows

```
"WebServerHost": {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
 <..skipping metadata...>
 "Properties": {
    "ImageId" : { "ami-1234" },
    "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "WebServerInstanceType" },
    "SecurityGroups" : [ {"Ref" : "WebServerSecurityGroup"} ],
    "SubnetId"       : "subnet-abcdef123",
```

and the security group looks as follows

```
"WebServerSecurityGroup" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "GroupDescription" : "Enable HTTP and SSH",
    "SecurityGroupIngress" : [
      {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "80", "ToPort" : "80", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"},
      {"IpProtocol" : "tcp", "FromPort" : "22", "ToPort" : "22", "CidrIp" : "0.0.0.0/0"}
    ]
  }
},
```

How can I create and then get that security group's ID?

Comment: I presume you're not creating the subnet in your cloudformation manifest?

Comment: Correct - I am using an existing subnet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to change this line:

```
"SecurityGroups" : [ {"Ref" : "WebServerSecurityGroup"} ],
```

to this:

```
"SecurityGroupIds" : [ {"Ref" : "WebServerSecurityGroup"} ],
```

Per the [Cloudformation documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-instance.html#cfn-ec2-instance-securitygroupids) on the topic, the `SecurityGroups` attribute is only valid for EC2 security groups. You're using VPC, so you need to use `SecurityGroupIds`.

Comment: That gives the same error unfortunately. If I do ```"SecurityGroupIds" : [ "sg-12345" ]``` then it works. I think I somehow I need to translate that literal security group snippet into a reference after it is created.

Comment: In that case, you have something else going on. I'm doing this **exact** thing in a few of my cfn manifests, and they're working perfectly. I'm not sure if resource order is important with CFN (I've never checked), but you may consider trying to define the SG first in your manifest.

Comment: Good idea - I'll try experimenting with those options and update.

Comment: I have up [a gist](https://gist.github.com/ftclausen/292aef2ff55477711d89#file-gistfile1-json-L143-L144) for the complete manifest. I am using the CF tutorial template except it has been modified to use a subnet and with my attempt at applying a security group there.

Comment: Can you please update your question with the full error message you're getting?

Comment: Actually, I was daft, your advice worked. It failed for another reason after making your suggested changes (typo in VPC for security group) - I did not catch that and thought it was the original problem.

Comment: Hah, excellent. Glad you're up and running.

Comment: Just wanted to chime in that I ran into this exact issue using troposphere (https://github.com/cloudtools/troposphere) because I forgot to use `Ref()` and was also using `SecurityGroups` instead of `SecurityGroupIds`.  @EEAA's solution worked perfectly!

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I had read the AWS documentation however it did not click that this was the problem. I believe the docs on this could be a lot clearer - actually saying that the "SecurityGroups" parameter is for use in the EC2 classic mode would be helpful.

Comment: This answer indirectly helped to resolve my problem. Thanks very much @EEAA